# Unexpected token in React after installed ESlint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a problem with unexpected token in **React.js** after I started to use **ESlint**.

Here is my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
 parser: "babel-eslint",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
  "jsx": true,
  "modules": true
 },
"rules": {
 "max-len": [1, 120, 2, {ignoreComments: true}],
 "linebreak-style": 0,
 "semi": [2, "never"],
 "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
 "react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
 "react/prefer-stateless-function": [0]
 },
"globals": {
 "document": true,
 "localStorage": true
 },
"extends": ["airbnb-base"]
}
```

In index.js I have this definition:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

`Syntax error (unexpected token)` is in `<App />`. If I add quotes to  like this `'<App />'`, it's working. Why?
I dont't want to use quotes in components calls. 
This problem is everywhere with JSX syntax. Here too:

```
const App = () => (
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

);

Probably I must add some rule to `.eslintrc`. Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to add an ESLint plugin e.g. this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react

Comment: Hello Matt, I have this plugin installed, but it's not working.

Comment: When you write '<App />' it renders the component?

Comment: Hello gabrielwr. Yes, as you write.

Comment: @ŠtefanOndáš you need to add it to your config, take a look:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react

Comment: airbnb-base does not have react into it, try using the eslint-config-airbnb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all replies. I have installed all of plugins which you wrote.
At the end, problem was in my webpack config file. I forgot to set query -
presets in loaders. Now it's working.

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
}
```